# How to change the opensips default port number 5060 to some other port?

Tags: port, sip, sip-server, opensips

I tried changing the opensips port number form 5060 to some other port in opensips.cfg file.

`port=5060` - I changed this to `port=6060`.

Restarted opensips after this. But this change is not working. How to make sure this is working?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try to install webmin as http interface to re-configure your sip server. Webmin has worked well for basic web based editing of CentOS settings like ports, etc. I've used it on FreePBX  and that is CentOS too. I changed port setting on FreePBX using web min including bootloader label too.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible to change the opensips default listening port as well as interface.

You can listen on a particular interface and port like this:

```
listen=192.168.1.90:8090
```

This will surely work.